# How to select variables with spaces in python datar package using f expression

Tags: python

Want to select variables using pipe ( >> ) expression. However not able to write the code if variable name has spaces. How to do it using f expression from datar package?

```
df
   frequency11 Virus Particle
     <float64>       <object>
0     11972.61        NoVirus
1     11938.30        NoVirus
2     11844.97        NoVirus
3     11811.40        NoVirus
4     11940.01        NoVirus
```

To select variable `frequency11` we can do

```
df >> select( f.frequency11 )
```

However when selecting `Virus Particle` not able to do it. Its giving error as invalid syntax

```
df >> select( f."Virus Particle")
```

```
    tt>> select( f."Virus Particle")
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

f-expression document : https://pwwang.github.io/datar/f/

Package : https://pypi.org/project/datar/

Comment: The documentation you linked say to use `f["Virus Particle"]`

Comment: Package author here. @PeterWood has the right answer.